# Add a menu button based on Email body contents

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Some of the emails in our inboxes relate to support tickets raised on the helpdesk. Each email generated has a specific string like "--- Please do not remove this line! Ticket#48632 ---" which is used by the ticketing system to identify the appropriate ticket and append the email to the ticket if the tag line is found.

unfortunately for us, this isn't a hyperlink, so we have to open the helpdesk system, cut/paste the ticket number to view the ticket, not a huge pain, but it would be nice to have some form of hyperlinking or button to open up the ticket (in the browser) when the email body contains the string.

I guess this would involve parsing the email body, looking for the string "--- Please do not remove this line! Ticket#" and then creating a hyperlink that includes the ticket number (this is supported by the helpdesk system).

So...

1. Does Outlook support menu bar buttons that can appear conditionally based on whether the "search the email body for something" finds a result, and set the destination URL conditional on the results found in the body.
2. Does Outlook allow for extra "areas" (apologies for the poor terminology), but I was wondering if the email pane could be enhanced (conditionally) to show a section that may include the hyperlink button, but could also be used to make a REST call to the ticketing system, and display additional ticket information like Status, who's assigned etc.

If someone can explain if conditional menus are possible,and the same with extra display pains, and more importantly, what the correct "terms" are that I would use to search for ideas/solutions.

I have found that there are lots of examples of parsing an email body for a string, so I know that can be done, I'm not sure if the results of this can be translated into something that controls the display.

Comment: Why does the button presence have to be conditional? Why not just have it there all the time, and you press it only when relevant? (And let the macro tell you if by mistake you happen to press it when it isn't relevant.) I'm sorry, I don't get the point of your seemingly very contrived approach. I suggest you try something, then ask about any specific problems you run into, showing what you have tried. Right now this question is way too open-ended.

Comment: The button doesn't have to be conditional, I was asking what was possible/practical. If for the reasons stated, it's not a good idea, then a check at the time of pressing would seem a practical solution.

Comment: I've accomplished something much more simple for a similar ask by automatically creating the hyperlink in the email body.  Depends if you feel you really need the capabilities in the manner you describe.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

> 1.Does Outlook support menu bar buttons that can appear conditionally based on whether the "search the email body for something" finds a result, and set the destination URL conditional on the results found in the body.

The Fluent UI is a static thing. You are not allowed to make dynamic customizations at runtime. Only few controls allows to add items (or buttons) dynamically. But you can enable or disable controls at runtime dynamically. For example, based on the body parse you can enable your controls or not. Use callbacks to implement this strategy.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

> 2.Does Outlook allow for extra "areas" (apologies for the poor terminology), but I was wondering if the email pane could be enhanced (conditionally) to show a section that may include the hyperlink button, but could also be used to make a REST call to the ticketing system, and display additional ticket information like Status, who's assigned etc.

Of course, you can use the Outlook Form Regions to display the required information on the pane withing the Inspector window. See [Outlook Form Regions Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942843%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks,This is just what I was after. I appreciate your input here.